# Automapper 4.2 Unity Inject MapperConfiguration

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, automapper-4

I can't quite figure how to convert the following structure map implementation to unity.

```
public AutoMapperRegistry()
{
    var profiles =
        from t in typeof (AutoMapperRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes()
        where typeof (Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t)
        select (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
    });

    For<MapperConfiguration>().Use(config);
    For<IMapper>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(ctx.GetInstance));
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityAutoRegistration/ I've used it several times and it works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following extension methods

```
    public static IUnityContainer RegisterMapper(this IUnityContainer container)
    {
        return container
        .RegisterType<MapperConfiguration>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c =>
               new MapperConfiguration(configuration =>
               {
                   configuration.ConstructServicesUsing(t => container.Resolve(t));
                   foreach (var profile in c.ResolveAll<Profile>())
                       configuration.AddProfile(profile);
               })))
        .RegisterType<IConfigurationProvider>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>()))
        .RegisterType<IMapper>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper()));
    }
```

and

```
    public static IUnityContainer RegisterMappingProfile<T>(this IUnityContainer container)
        where T : Profile
    {
        return RegisterMappingProfile(container, typeof(T));
    }
```

In my unity container config class I call them

```
        container.RegisterMapper();
        container.RegisterMappingProfile<WebProfile>();
```

Answer (score 6):

Ran across the same issue, finally got it working by doing the following

```
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(x =>
        {
              //Your configuration for your mapper
        });

        var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

        container.RegisterInstance(mapper);
```

Comment: where does the container comes from? where should I put this code for registering it with the unity inject?

Comment: @Eric thanks for this, I have spent a day trying to get this working.

Comment: @Thunderer the container is IUnityContainer and should be in your UnitiyConfig.cs file